# WPF Databinding on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have made a simple application with one class called `dog`. In the code behind file of my mainwindow I've made a `public ObservableCollection<Dog> dogNameCollection = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();`. Inside the class `Dog` is just one propertie, the name. I want to bind the propertie name to a datagrid.

I added this line to my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file: 
`this.dgDogNames.DataContext = this.dogNameCollection;`.

The `DataGridTextColumn` looks like this:
`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>`.

So where is my mistake? Maybe someone of you can help me.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="txtBoxDogName" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
    <Button Name="btnSetValue" Margin="5" Padding="5" Content="Set name" Click="btnSetValue_Click"/>

    <DataGrid Margin="5" Name="dgDogNames" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
namespace BindingTest
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Dog> dogNameCollection = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dgDogNames.DataContext = this.dogNameCollection;
    }

    private void btnSetValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dogNameCollection.Add(new Dog(this.txtBoxDogName.Text));
    }
}
}
```

`Dog.cs`

```
namespace BindingTest
{
public class Dog
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; }
    }

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `this.dgDogNames.DataContext = this.dogNameCollection;` => `this.dgDogNames.ItemsSource = this.dogNameCollection;` or bind ItemsSource: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`

Comment: @ASh now it works. Thanks.